# Correlation of outputs in Bayesian hierarchical regression

Tags: interpretation, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian

I am using a Bayesian hierarchical regression (stan_lmer in rstanarm) to do a MCMC sample of the posterior for the mixed effects model y ~ A * B + (1|C). Although I have done other Bayesian regressions in the past this is the first time that I am using the hierarchial approach for a mixed effects model.

The model diagnostics seem pretty good. The only parameter of concern is that the effective sample size is less than 10% of the total sample size for the group (C) mean parameters, but I guess that is to be expected since we have 35 different groups in C. Even so, it looks like the posterior predictive distribution captures the essence of the data: [image: Posterior Predictive Distribution Replicates]

Overall, it seems like the fit was good. However, I am unfamiliar with this type of model and there is one result that surprises and concerns me. Specifically, I have a very high degree of correlation between the overall intercept and each group intercept: [image: Correlation Between Overall Intercept and Group Intercept]

I only show one group, but they all look like that, each is strongly negatively correlated with the overall intercept. I know that the individual group intercepts are not particularly of interest, what we are interested in is the variance between groups, and the variance between groups looks fine (accounting for about 6 times the residual standard deviation). But this degree of correlation with the actual intercepts and the overall intercept is strange to me.

Is this typical for these kinds of models? How am I supposed to interpret this? There is no multi-colinearity issue in the data, so I don't know how to think about colinearity in the model output. Any insight would be tremendously useful.

EDIT: it seems like perhaps there is a certain amount of error. When more of the error is put into the overall intercept then less of it goes into the individual group terms. Is that typical or does it indicate a failure in the model?

Comment: I am no expert, but that's what you would expect? to achieve a group level average you add overall intercept and group intercept, so to match the data the lower overall intercept is the higher group intercept and vv

Comment: @seanv507 thanks for replying. So you think it may be just a typical feature of these models. It is my first time using one so seeing it made me nervous.

Comment: yes I believe it is to be expected